# Chartboost with statusbar hidden

Tags: iphone, ipad, chartboost

I have integrated More apps of chartboost, but i hv the status bar in the app,which i dont want to remove.So the header of more apps is getting cover by status bar,any way to make it fine?

Comment: Those who downvoted, can give reason?  for Those who faced issue like this, chartboost said thats an bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which iOS version are you targeting?

- If you're targeting iOS 5:

I don't  know the architecture of your app but according to your description, the autoresizingMask and/or autoresizesSubviews property of your games "container view" may not be set correctly.

- If you're targeting iOS 6 only:

If you're using the "Auto Layout" feature already, then probably check out the following [guide](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2).

Either way check out the [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5) on auto resizing etc.

Comment: i am just calling " [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showMoreApps];
  [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] cacheMoreApps];
"  on button tap. nothing else, but status bar is cropping the more apps top

Comment: I see, then it's probably still a bug in Chartboost framework as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you're using the latest version of the Chartboost SDK. That bug was fixed in SDK version 3.1, you can grab v3.1.1 here: https://help.chartboost.com/downloads/ios

If you need any other assistance, feel free to check out a fully integrated example project here: https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples

Comment: yes i did that.I connected with chartboost team, they mentioned that bug has been resolved in latest sdk.But they did tested my version and got the bug again with new sdk.